# You must call removeView

Tags: android

I already tried almost all topics about this problem, and didn't have the soluction for my problem.
ok. I have a TableLayout with some views, and i want to add some views more when I recive some information from another Activity. Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.interview);

    params.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
    table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id._tabe_inscription_client);
    table.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    table.setShrinkAllColumns(true); 
            rowClient = new TableRow(this);
    TextView client = new TextView(this);
    client.setText("Cliente empresa");
    client.setTextSize(18);
    client.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    client.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    rowClient.setLayoutParams(params);
    rowClient.addView(client, params);
    TableRow roweClient = new TableRow(this);
    EditText eClient = new EditText(this);
    eClient.setLayoutParams(params);
    eClient.setTextSize(18);
    eClient.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    eClient.setText("Escriba el nombre de la empresa");
    eClient.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    roweClient.addView(eClient, params);


              ...more views...

            table.addView(rowClient);
    table.addView(roweClient);
    table.addView(rowContact);
    table.addView(roweContact);
    table.addView(rowInterested);
    table.addView(rowEmailContact);
    table.addView(roweEmailContact);
    table.addView(rowCellphoneContact);
    table.addView(roweCellphoneContact);
    table.addView(rowProductst);
```

Everything is work until here. And here is where I need to add views.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Productos Recibidos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        if (data != null) {
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            child = bundle.getStringArrayList("child");
            isChecked = bundle.getBooleanArray("selected");
            table.addView(rowProductst); // here is my problem  
        }
    }


}
```

my XML  :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
android:id="@+id/_host_layout">

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/_tabe_inscription_client"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</TableLayout>
```

log:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.telconnet.ventas/com.telconnet.ventas.pre_sale.Interview}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3363)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3406)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3345)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3216)
    at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:429)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3161)
    at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:411)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3137)
    at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:402)
    at com.telconnet.ventas.pre_sale.Interview.onActivityResult(Interview.java:202)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5314)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3359)
    ... 11 more

This is my frist post here so I hope make it in te correct way.
Can anyone help me?? Please.

Comment: Try `setContentView(table);` after : table.addView(rowProductst);

Comment: @mt0s does not work bro!

Comment: You have already added `rowProductst` View and you are adding it again when you return to the Activity and triggers the `onActivityResult`

Comment: It is working !! Really thanks bro! I have tried with another view, that just for post here, but maybe I made a mistek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly:

1. Try to avoid defining your layout explicitly in code. You could obviously define it in xml and load it (your code will shorten).
2. As you see there is an exception thrown in ViewGroup (addViewInnter method is responsible for throwing this exception):

   ```
   private void addViewInner(View child, int index, LayoutParams params,
       boolean preventRequestLayout) {

   if (mTransition != null) {
       // Don't prevent other add transitions from completing, but cancel remove
       // transitions to let them complete the process before we add to the container
       mTransition.cancel(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING);
   }

   if (child.getParent() != null) {
       throw new IllegalStateException("The specified child already has a parent. " +
               "You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.");
   ...
   ```

   }

Obviously the rowProductst view that you add in onActivityResult already contains parent view. To overcome this obstacle:

1. Find out why rowProductst has parent view. You have to simply invoke:

   ```
     ((ViewGroup)parentView).removeView(rowProductst);
   ```

and add it again.

1. You could inflate new view as well by calling LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE from context (context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)) and this will definately work.

Please, mind also that your code doesn't look good.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it is very useful. you mean is bad practrice add programmatically all the rows in my code? what do you recommend me?

Comment: Well,it is up to the problem you deal with. 
1. I noticed that you define some string explicitly in code. Strings should be defined in your xml values ( @jihonora pointed it also). 
2. Setting up TableLayout with configuration parameters defining how it should look like can be handled in xml ( for example: _table.setStretchAllColumns(true)_ is equivalent to _android_stretchColumns=true_ ).
I did not mean adding views dynamically to the containers. If situation requires it then it is totally good practice.
Generally my approach about setting up views is to handle it in xml as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

You have already added `rowProductst` View and you are adding it again when you return to the Activity and triggers the `onActivityResult`

///////

After you add a new View to layout you have to call [setContentView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29)

Answer (score 0):

Another option here. In `onActivityResult` you need to inflate a new `View` for the element you want to insert, like:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Productos Recibidos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        if (data != null) {
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            child = bundle.getStringArrayList("child");
            isChecked = bundle.getBooleanArray("selected");
            // We will inflate the view with the table as a parent but not append it
            View newView = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.your_row_layout, table, false);
            // Refresh the data in your view
            // ...
            // Finally add it to the table
            table.addView(newView); // here is my problem  
        }
    }
}
```

I also noticed lots of hard-coded strings, you should try to avoid that practice.

Comment: hi! Thanks for the answer. I tried and is working, but my code is getting bigger. What do you mean with hard-code Strings, you mean load eveything from de xml?

Comment: Exactly. You can do it with `getString(R.string.string_name)`. I know first-hand that code can get big but it's the right way to do it.